# Is it necessary to have a Service User Account to deploy an ASP.NET Core Application as a Windows Service?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, windows-services

I have been developing custom API services and hosting them on a windows server as windows services; of course, it's reached a point where the work has become tedious and redundant not to mention very buggy and insecure. So now am exploring ways of leveraging the advantages of ASP.NET Core while still deploying them as windows services. What I can't understand is the purpose of setting up Service User Accounts is it necessary? What is the importance of this? Can I skip the User Account step and just deploy them manually without the need for a User Account?

The documentation in question is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/windows-service?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got an answer from [AspNetCore.Docs Github Repository](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/14818)